# Wrap a recursive Component with a higher-order component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say that I have a simple component, and I want to log when it mounts. I can do this with a HOC that takes my component, defines a `componentDidMount` function, and returns a new component. Then I can create a new component `let MyLoggedComponent = withLog(MyComponent)` and use `MyLoggedComponent` where I want.

But let's say I have a recursive component, that is somewhere in it's render function it calls itself again:

```
class MyRecursiveComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
  ... <MyRecursiveComponent />
  ...
}
```

Now, when I wrap this component `let MyLoggedComponent = withLog(MyRecursiveComponent)`, only the outer instance of `MyRecursiveComponent` will be wrapped, and `componentDidMount` function will only fire once.

How can I wrap a recursive component so that it effects all instances of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get wrapped component right in the `MyRecursiveComponent`:

```
class MyRecursiveComponent extends React.Component {
  const MyRecursiveComponentWithLog = withLog(MyRecursiveComponent);
  render() {
    ... 
    <MyRecursiveComponentWithLog />
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I would prefer a solution where I don't have to modify the wrapped component.